# What is the best way to maintain a Bluetooth connection after app is killed in Android?

Tags: android, service, bluetooth

I am developing an application in Android that connects to a Bluetooth device. On occasion, an alarm created by the alarm manager goes off and is supposed to send information to the connected Bluetooth device. My question is, what is the best way to make this connection so that I can communicate with the device when the activity has been stopped (app is closed). I have read about intent services, foreground services, remote messenger services, and have not found any source that says the best way to make a service that won't end when the application is closed to host Bluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

create your service class extend service and bluetoothadapter init in yourservice oncreate()

Comment: When the activity is destroyed (app is closed) the service is destroyed as well. How do I keep the service from being destroyed and keep the connection with the Bluetooth device?

Answer (score 0):

## Foreground Service

First of all I suggest using a [foreground service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services#Foreground).

The service runs indefinitely and the app will be recreated each time it is killed (by user or by system).
In addition foreground services are also excluded from Oreos [background execution limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background).

Check out [this](https://medium.com/@er.abhishek.luthra/effect-of-swiping-an-android-app-in-recent-app-list-1f7984aa4abc) post for a detailed description and test of Android service's lifecycle. Please also be aware that testing the lifecycle of services can be quite a struggle. Debugging tools usually loose connection to a service once the app is swiped off of recent used apps list or killed otherwise.

## Service lifecycle

Once you set up the foreground service you should make use of service's lifecycle hooks as pointed out by [Yongho](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43268122/4189142) to keep a reference to peripherals.

For example you could create and assign BluetoothScannerCallback to an instance variable in `OnCreate()` like so:

```
OnCreate() {
    _scannerCallback = CreateScannerCallback();
}
```

This way you'll be notified about connection losses. Also use Androids Bluetooth Default Adapter inside the service in order to keep connections to Bluetooth devices alive when the host application is moved to background or killed (and recreated).

You should also deinitialize all references in `OnDestroy()`.